# Python program that reads file, then calculates sum, average, min, max, and give message if it only has one number in it or is empty

Tags: python

```
def main():
    filename = input("Enter a file name: ")
    with open(filename) as f:
        data = [int(line) for line in f]
        if len(data) > 2:
            print('The smallest number in the file is: ', + min(data))
            print('The largest number in the file is: ', "{:,}".format(+ max(data)))
            print('The total sum of the number in the file is: ', "{:,}".format(sum(data)))
            print('The average from the numbers in the file is: ', "{:,.2f}".format(sum(data)/len(data)))
        elif len(data) == 1:
            print ('There is only one number in your file to process.')
        else:
            print('There are no numbers in your file to process.')         
        f.close()

main()
```

Comment: Okay, what is the question?

Comment: I continue to get the error message: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\n' when entering an empty file. I'm not sure how to get around this.

Comment: Please add those details to the question.

Comment: @LinzG That should be part of the question, not a comment. Also it's better if you post the whole traceback.

Comment: I apologize.  This is my first time using this site, and it's been a long day.  I will remember that next time.

Comment: @LinzG you can always edit your question and add these details to it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, I think the problem is with your data, to get around that, you could use something like:

```
lines = filter(None, (line.strip() for line in f))
data = [int(line) for line in lines if line.isnumeric()]
```

Please note that this only addresses the exception you're getting - I haven't gone through the rest of the code and verified the logic.

Comment: Perfect!  It worked beautifully.  Thank you so very much!